# C++ : semget : Returns ENOENT

Tags: c++, semaphore

```
    #include <sys/sem.h>
 #include <sys/stat.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


main () {
    string key = "/m/lb1/activity.log";
    int sem_key = ftok (key.c_str (), 1);
    if (access (key.c_str (), R_OK) == 0)
        printf ("keypath is accessible \n");
    printf("sem_getid : %d", sem_key);
    errno = 0;
    int sem_id = semget (sem_key, 0, 0655);
    printf( " sem get val :%d :%s\n", sem_id, strerror(errno));
}
$ ./a.out
keypath is accessible
sem_getid : 16850172 sem get val :-1 :No such file or directory


ls -l /m/lb1/activity.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 apple g6 0 Feb 9 19:08 /m/lb1/activity.log
```

The "access" call returns 0; so the keypath gets printed out. However, the semget is returning an ENOENT (No such file or directory)

sem_getid : 16850172
sem get val :-1 :No such file or directory

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

`semget` gets an *existing* semaphore set unless you specify `IPC_CREAT` or `IPC_PRIVATE` in the third argument. From `man semget`:

> ```
> ENOENT
>     No semaphore set exists for key and semflg did not specify IPC_CREAT.
> ```

In this case, `ENOENT` means that the semaphore set didn't exist, rather than meaning the path didn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The `sem_key` you pass to semget is not a filename or path, its just an arbitrary 32-bit integer.  The namespace of possible semaphore keys is not related to the file name space in any way.

So you need to pick some (integer) key value to use, and you need to actually create the key before using it, by calling semget with IPC_CREAT first.

Comment: With respect to the previous answer by Chris Dodd is inexact because the key is generated by the [ftok](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/ftok.html)() function which takes a path and an integer id and returns a key suitable for semget().